# Navigation Bar issues on Blogger

Tags: html, css, navbar

Im trying to build a website on blogger and am facing a lot of issues with the navigation bar and menu.
I want to :

1. Make the Navigation bar stick to the top so it scrolls along with the page
2. Make the menu/navigation bar span the whole width of the page

heres the code that I used:

```
 <div class = "navbar">  
<a href='#LINK'>Home</a>

<a href='#link'>About Us </a> 

<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Tarbiyah Program 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      
<a href='#link'> Year 1</a>
      
<a href='#link'>Year 2 </a>

<a href='#link'>Year 3</a>

<a href='#link'>Year 4 </a>

<a href='#link'> Monthly Points </a>

<a href='#link'> Quizzes </a>

    </div>
  </div> 

<a href='#link'>Summer Camp </a> 

<a href='#link'>Classes & Events </a> 


<a href='#link'>Blog </a>

<a href='#link'>Contact Us </a>  
    </div>
```

and the CSS I used:

-----NAVBAR-----

```
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: black;
}



.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: black;
  font-family: arial;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #BDE0f9;
  color: black;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #EC549D;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {

}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: what you want exactly

Answer (score 0):

i think with this you'r good to go

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1020;
}
```